# Reading text file with php for javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to read a text file line by line updated by a python script with php. From there, I'm trying to convert it into javascript (for google maps API). I am stuck at converting php to javascript.

```
var line = <?php
    $file_handle = fopen('posts_replied_to.txt','r');
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($file_handle);
        echo $line;
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Will line keep changing every time $line does or will it only take the last $line value? I need to do operations for each line. Hopefully I made sense....

Comment: Your JavaScript variable `line` will end up with the **entire** contents of the .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do javascript operations on each line, you'll want to store each line in an array element or similar:

```
<?php
    $arr = [];
    $file_handle = fopen('posts_replied_to.txt','r');
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $arr[] = fgets($file_handle);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
?>    
var lines = <?php json_encode($arr); ?>;

lines.forEach(function (line) {
  // do stuff with line
});
```

An even simpler method would be to pass javascript the entire file as a string, and split it by line breaks to make the array:

```
var file = <?php echo json_encode(file_get_contents('posts_replied_to.txt')); ?>;
var lines = file.split(/\r?\n/g);
lines.forEach(function (line) {
  // do stuff with line
});
```